# How do I set a VLC instance to run as a Live Wallpaper

Tags: vlc, desktop-background

I've seen an article describing how to use VLC as a live wallpaper for the desktop, however the options mentioned there only refer to Windows.

What would I need to do to achieve the same result?

Comment: sounds interesting - never tried.  Are you using KDE or Gnome.  If KDE - this link looks interesting.   If no, maybe something like it will work? http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=95522

Comment: I'm using Gnome 2

Answer (score 16, accepted):

VLC does support video as background. Simply run the cvlc command:

```
cvlc --video-wallpaper --no-audio /your/videofile
```

There are other helpful options to cvlc such as aspect ratio etc. You can find them using

```
vlc --help
```

If you still want icons on your desktop you may need to take a look at [xwinwrap](http://swik.net/xwinwrap), but it requires a little digging. There is an option to set movies as background. I dont know how to do it with VLC but it has been done with mplayer.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the name of the video from appearing every time it plays again?.

Comment: Simply add --no-video-title-show to your command line.

Comment: Is there a way to show the video wallpaper on all Ubuntu Unity desktops? I use the standard 4 desktops, but vlc shows only on one of them.

Answer (score 1):

vlc does not work on either windows or Linux for the backdrop.  The only thing it does is play full screen with no controls.  It does NOT place the video in the background.  I have been working with it for over two years and that is the best I can get out of it!