# Interactive Desktop Wallpapers

Tags: software-recommendation, desktop-background

Is there any interactive wallpapers like for example a background of a pond with some fishes and you could click on the fishes. I know this will consume a little more ram, cpu and video but it would look really nice.

I know there are slideshow wallpapers and wallpaper series that depend of the day of time, but in this case, wallpapers that the user can interact with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiz does have interactive effects like water, writing in fire, and snow. If you have the graphics for it look into it-
[CompizFusion](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompositeManager/CompizFusion)

Also this may help,
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1099655 says that xwinwrap could be used to diplay movies or screensavers.

Here they say there might be some for KDE,
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1073107&page=2

Just recently found that you can run VLC in wallpaper mode, [How do I set a VLC instance to run as a Live Wallpaper](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58657/how-do-i-set-a-vlc-instance-to-run-as-a-live-wallpaper)

Answer (score 2):

[Xwinwrap](http://tech.shantanugoel.com/projects/linux/shantz-xwinwrap)

I used this in the past display a video wallpaper. It basically starts in the foreground of the desktop. You can use any screensaver you have on your computer to run in the background or specify a video. On my system the icons on the desktop would flicker so I disabled them. But that is the only snag I had with it.

This is how you can launch the glmatrix screensaver

```
 ./xwinwrap -ov -fs -- /usr/lib/xscreensaver/glmatrix -root -window-id WID
```

This will run it in the background like your wallpaper. Any other video or screensaver can be launched this way.

It simple to use but you have to install from source(or at least I had to)