# How to set a .mp4 as a Wallpaper?

Tags: video, desktop-background

Is there a way to set an mp4 as an ubuntu wallpaper? Or any other format as long as it is an animation?

Comment: I've been wondering this myself about possibly using a .gif

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, it depends on what you're willing to do.

You can actually set your background as the video that's playing in VLC. Granted, you'll have to have VLC playing constantly and have the video on loop, but you'll get the desired effect.

There's also the side affect that you lose  your icons, but if you don't have icons on your desktop (like me) that's not a big deal.

**Using VLC**:

Just launch VLC from the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) via `cvlc --video-wallpaper --no-audio /path/to/your/video`

As a note, I took this information [from this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58657/how-do-i-set-a-vlc-instance-to-run-as-a-live-wallpaper). This question *could* be a duplicate of that.

Here's a quick video showing what VLC does:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpRU7iWKloI&feature=youtu.be

You're going to see the VLC title bar, so it's not the most perfect of solutions, but it's something.

**Using XWinWrap & Mplayer**:

Another option is to follow the steps given [in this tutorial here](http://www.n00bsonubuntu.net/content/how-to-install-my-video-wallpaper-script-on-ubuntu-13-04/). I haven't actually tried this myself, so I can't vouch for the success in any newer versions.

Comment: thanks the VLC worked now I got this as a background: http://youtu.be/dgKqxu05NnY

Comment: just an update, the vlc kept crashing after about 2-5 mins, the other solution however works perfectly(no desktop icons) so far.

Comment: the link to the other solution is broken. Can you give me any keywords so I can find a copy elsewhere on the web? @wizgot

Comment: This is not working for me on Ubuntu 20: `cvlc --video-wallpaper --no-audio ahsoka.webm -> VLC media player 3.0.9.2 Vetinari (revision 3.0.9.2-0-gd4c1aefe4d)`