# How can I set the live stream from ISS HD Earth View as my desktop background?

Tags: vlc, desktop-background, video-streaming, livestreamer

I would like to display the [High Definition Earth-Viewing System (HDEV)](http://eol.jsc.nasa.gov/HDEV/) Live stream from International Space Station as a desktop background on Ubuntu 15.04

Related questions:

- [How can I set the live video feed from the ISS as my desktop
  background? (superuser)](https://superuser.com/questions/750949/how-can-i-set-the-live-video-feed-from-the-iss-as-my-desktop-background)
- [Use video for wallpaper](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370624/use-video-for-wallpaper)
- [How do I set a VLC instance to run as a Live Wallpaper](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58657/how-do-i-set-a-vlc-instance-to-run-as-a-live-wallpaper)

Comment: +1 for interesting question!  I've often wondered about similar things...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Installation

1. Install [vlc](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vlc/) :
   `sudo apt-get install vlc`
2. Install [livestreamer](https://livestreamer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html) :
   `sudo apt-get install livestreamer`
3. Install [python-librtmp](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/vivid/python-librtmp) :
   `sudo apt-get install python-librtmp`

### High Definition Earth Viewing System (720p)

**HD stream**

This command displays [High Definition Earth-Viewing System (HDEV)](http://eol.jsc.nasa.gov/HDEV/) on wallpaper mode, full screen, with no window decoration and no audio.

```
livestreamer http://ustream.tv/channel/iss-hdev-payload best --player 'vlc -I dummy --video-wallpaper --no-video-title-show --noaudio'
```

**HD stream (720p) with Audio (crew/mission control conversations)**

This command displays the [HDEV](http://eol.jsc.nasa.gov/HDEV/) and add sound from another stream, [Live ISS](http://www.ustream.tv/channel/live-iss-stream), accompanied by audio of conversations between the crew and Mission Control.

```
livestreamer http://www.ustream.tv/embed/9408562?html5ui best --player "cvlc --no-video" & livestreamer http://ustream.tv/channel/iss-hdev-payload best --player 'vlc -I dummy --video-wallpaper --no-video-title-show
```

### Live ISS Stream (480p)

Display the ISS Live stream (different viewpoint, on air more often)

**SD stream**

```
livestreamer http://ustream.tv/channel/iss-hdev-payload best --player 'vlc -I dummy --video-wallpaper --no-video-title-show'
```

**SD stream with Audio (crew/mission control conversations)**

```
livestreamer http://ustream.tv/channel/iss-hdev-payload best --player 'vlc -I dummy --video-wallpaper --no-video-title-show --noaudio'
```

### Bash ON/ OFF script

A simple script `iss-background.sh` for turning on and off the background.

```
#!/bin/bash
PS=`ps -ef`
if echo "$PS"|grep -q 'vlc -I dummy';
    then echo "off";
    kill $(ps aux | grep 'vlc -I dummy' | awk '{print $2}')
else echo "on";
    livestreamer http://www.ustream.tv/embed/9408562?html5ui best --player "cvlc --no-video" & livestreamer http://ustream.tv/channel/iss-hdev-payload best --player 'vlc -I dummy --video-wallpaper --no-video-title-show --noaudio'
fi
```

### Improved bash script

Just select the path of an icon you want to be displayed with notifications, or delete the third line `Icon="/path/to/nasa_icon.png` the two `-i $Icon` options)

```
#!/bin/bash
PS=`ps -ef`
Icon="/path/to/nasa_icon.png"

if echo "$PS"|grep -q 'vlc -I dummy';
    then notify-send -i $Icon "  ISS background OFF" \ "\"Houston, We've Got a Problem !\"";
    kill $(ps aux | grep 'vlc -I dummy' | awk '{print $2}')
else notify-send -i $Icon " ISS background ON" \ "Dowloading data from ISS...";
    livestreamer http://www.ustream.tv/embed/9408562?html5ui best --player "cvlc --no-video" & livestreamer http://ustream.tv/channel/iss-hdev-payload best --player 'vlc -I dummy --video-wallpaper --no-video-title-show --noaudio'
fi
```

Associate it with a launcher:
Just replace the following lines : `Icon=` , `Exec=`, and `Path=`,

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=ISS
Comment=Display ISS live stream as background
Icon=/PATH/TO/YOUR/icon.png
Exec=bash iss-background.sh
Path=/PATH/TO/YOUR/SCRIPT/
NoDisplay=false
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
```

### Troubleshooting :

- **Black screen** : International Space Station (ISS) is on the night side of the Earth.
- **Unity launcher is hidden** : I can't figure out a way to do it otherwise.

If one of the following occurs :

- **Blue screen**
- **No video**
- `error: No streams found on this URL`

it might be that :

> "The space station is experiencing a temporary loss of signal"

And you might want to check with your web browser if the videos are on air [HDEV](http://eol.jsc.nasa.gov/HDEV/) and [Live ISS](http://www.ustream.tv/channel/live-iss-stream).